# Why is the 'w' silent in "sword"?

Tags: pronunciation, pronunciation-vs-spelling, silent-letters, received-pronunciation

In RP English, the 'w' in "sword" is silent. [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sword) suggests /sɔːd/ and /soʊrd/.

Why? Are there other words like this? The 'w' is pronounced in words like "swollen", "swoop", "sworn" and "swore".

Comment: The W was pronounced in Old English, the pronunciation changed over time, but not the spelling.

Comment: Isn't that the story for most silent letters, that originally it was pronounced but pronunciation drifted faster than the spelling?

Comment: I'm wondering why this happened with "sword" but not with "sworn", and whether "sword" is the only word in which the 'w' drifted away.

Comment: @Malvolio: yes, for most, but for many, the spelling strangeness is due to inspiration by false etymology, for example, 'island'.

Comment: @Tim: 'answer'? 'coxswain'? 'who'?

Comment: Churchill supposedly said the Royal Navy's traditions consisted of "rum, sodomy, and the lash".  The word "coxswain" (pronounced *coxun*) -- like "boatswain" (often spelled "bo's'un" and always pronounced *bosun*), "forecastle" ("fo'c'stle", *foxul*), and "gunwhale" (*gunnel*) -- is a victim of a fourth proud tradition: reducing the King's English down to a mumble.

Comment: The "w" has also become silent in *toward* in American English.

Comment: Not only "sword" and "answer" but also "two"...

Comment: @PeterShor I’m always amazed by how differently American English is perceived by my fellow Americans than it is by me. (Read: I’ve never heard of such a thing, and surely never do so myself.)

Comment: @tchrist: *Merriam-Webster* and *American Heritage* both give [tɔrd] (rhymes with sword) as an alternate pronunciation. I say it that way myself, and if you started listening for it, I suspect you would hear it.

Comment: @PeterShor Sounds like people who pronounce *think* with a *t* not a *th*.  Then again, I always pronounce the *s* in that word, too, so for me it’s always [twɔr(d)z], which is quite a long distance now from [tɔrd]. I do usually drop the /d/ though myself, leaving just [twɔrz].

Comment: Some of the words with a silent w at the beginning obviously originate from German - wringen ( wring ), wrack ( wreck )...... is there a common "heritage" for the others? Sword presumably originates from the German word 'Schwert'......strange that the w in swear/swore is pronounced as the word swear also presumably originates from "schwören".....can anybody explain this?

Comment: @John, neither of those two words come from German. They are indigenous words in both languages, inherited from their common ancestor. The disappearance of w only occurred before /o/ and /u/ in stressed syllables, but also before /ə/ (schwa) in unstressed ones. That's why _swear_ still has the w, but its reduced form in _answer_ doesn't.

Comment: Just to add that I have heard several dialects/accents within American English pronounce the /w/ in sword. For example, if you watch Markiplier on YouTube, he will pronounce the word with a /w/. He's from Cincinnati, OH. I also have a friend from Michigan pronounce it like so. It's not incredibly common but it's still alive in some areas of American English!

Comment: Related: [Why is “conquer” pronounced /'kɔŋkɚ/ but not /'kɔŋkwɚ/?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/63538)

Comment: And [this one on ELL](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/266296/106592)

Answer (score 12):

I have actually heard someone pronounce the /w/, and not facetiously. It must be rather rare, though, and I might say it's a hypercorrection. In any case, my guess is that [wɔ] and [wo] have a tendency to become [ɔː] and [oʊ] in the neighbourhood of consonants such as [s] that don't change much in the presence of labialisation. The matter is complicated a bit by the spread of non-rhotic accents.

The original word was /sweord/, which according to the usual Old English reconstructed pronunciation would be [sweort] or [sweʊrt]. I imagine [eʊ] dropped to [əʊ] or [əu], which is an allophone of [o]. By this time the [w] had become vestigial and was ultimately dropped, but English spelling is far more conservative than its pronunciation, so the /w/ was retained.

Comment: Can you come up with any examples to support the theory of [swɔ] and [swo] drifting to [sɔː] and [soʊ]?

Comment: @Tim: I was going through the *eo* diphthong, which made a wide variety of transitions: *eower* → *your*, *(a)beornan* → *burn*, *seofon* → *seven*, *seoþan* → *seethe*, and *seoc* → *sick*.

Comment: Quite right, but your answer doesn't explain why 'swore' is pronounced with a W. See [my answer below](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/556497/365490)

Answer (score 10):

Appropriately it's silent in answer. I couldn't find any other root *-sw-* words with a silent *w*.

As for sword, I found this from H.L. Mencken's [*The American Language*](http://www.bartleby.com/185/12.html) from 1921:

> As for the consonants, the colonists
>   seem to have resisted valiantly that
>   tendency to slide over them which
>   arose in England after the
>   Restoration. Franklin, in 1768, still
>   retained the sound of *l* in such words
>   as *would* and *should*, a usage not met
>   with in England after the year 1700.
>   In the same way, according to Menner,
>   the *w* in *sword* was sounded in America
>   “for some time after Englishmen had
>   abandoned it.”

(There's a whole host of silent *w* s at the start of words but not after *s*, but they can be considered another "family": wring wrap wrong wrist write wraith wreath wraparound wreck wrath wreak wreck wrench wreckage wrecker wrestle wren wriggle wretched wrest wrinkle wristlet wristwatch writ write writhe wrought wry.)

Comment: I'd say that the "wh*" belong to another family. Didn't think of "answer". Yes, the line is fuzzy and subjective.

Comment: I'm with @Tim: those are "silent" for a different reason.

Comment: Yeah, there's a whole host of those (wring wrap wrong wrist write wraith wreath wraparound wreck wrath wreak wreck wrench wreckage wrecker wrestle wren wriggle wretched wrest wrinkle wristlet wristwatch writ write writhe wrought wry). I'll edit my answer with some more info.

Comment: Those /wr/ ones aren't really silent as such—it's just that labialised and non-labialised /r/ have merged in most dialects. In AmE and BrE, they're normally both labialised (so ‘ring’ sort of really starts with an unwritten w); in IrE, they tend to be unrounded (so the written w is ‘silent’); and in ScE and some other dialects, they're still distinct, so /r/ is [r] and /wr/ is [wr].

Answer (score 10):

<w> is there because it was pronounced after the advent of printing press. So, the spelling stayed, but pronunciation changed. In three cases, andsƿarian > answer, sƿeord > sword, tƿa > two, <w> is there, but not pronounced.

On the other hand, <w> (or its OE  <ƿ>) is not there in some words because they were not pronounced by the time printing took over: OE sƿilch > such, sƿa > so

Comment: Is 'ƿ' some code that I don't know for 'w'? IPA? Cherokee? Futhark?

Comment: Well, they call it wynn: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wynn and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_English_Latin_alphabet

Answer (score 2):

[This answer on ELL](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/266296/) has explained the reason why the W is silent in *sword* but pronounced in *swore*. That answer is rather long, but I'll simplify it here:

Between 900–1400 AD, there was a sound change through which a **W** was lost when it was preceded by a [s] or a [t] and followed by a back vowel [ɒ ɔ o ɑ]. [[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonological_history_of_English#Until_Middle_English)]

The W in *two* and *sword* is silent because of that reason (i.e. **[t, s] [w] [back vowel]**).

*Swore, sworn* and *swollen* also lost their W's at one point due to the same reason, but were later on restored due to analogy<sup>**1**</sup> with *swear* and *swell*. *Swear* and *swell* hadn't lost their W's because they had front vowels after the W. [[Trask's Historical Linguistics](https://books.google.com/books?redir_esc=y&id=mQZSAQAAIAAJ&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=swear)]

---

<sup>1. [Analogical change](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analogical_change#Creation,_maintenance_and_restoration) is a type of language change in which some forms are deliberately changed merely to make them look more like other forms.</sup>

Comment: I recently came across another example of analogy mentioned in [this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/556195/365490), it says that the plural of 'book' was 'beek', but due to analogy with other regular forms, its plural has changed to 'book**s**'.

Answer (score 0):

Just a theory: As  sword is a thing of knights and noblemen.
The silent w may be due to Norman-French pronunciation habits and this pronunciation was generally accepted.

The w in spelling shows the origin of the word and its connection with German Schwert. With the w-spelling it is clear at once that the word does not belong to the word family "sort".