# Podiatrist vs. pedometer vs. pedophile?

Tags: latin, greek, roots

I was just discussing oddities of English with a friend, and I realized something that neither of us could explain.

- A podiatrist is a foot doctor.
- A podium is something you stand behind when giving a speech
- A pedometer is a device which counts
  your steps.
- A pedophile is someone with a sexual interest in
  children.

So what the heck?  [Apparently pod and ped are Latin and Greek](http://membean.com/wrotds/ped-foot) respectively roots for "foot", so that I get.  But then apparently pedo is Greek and is ["a combining form meaning “child,” used in the formation of compound words"](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/pedo-).  So uh, huh??  I mean, why isn't a pedometer a device for measuring children and a pedophile someone with a foot fetish...?

Comment: Originally, a *podium* is something you stand *on* (when getting a medal, for example). A *lectern* is something you stand *behind* when giving a speech. But *podium* has been so misused as to now mean lectern.

Comment: I believe you've answered your own question... the words have different origin languages, and are consistent with respect to _those_ languages.

Comment: RE: podium - Oops, yes I suppose that is correct.  Still, my question remains a puzzling one to me.

Comment: OK so there are different roots, sure... but still, if Ped is greek for foot, and pedo is Greek for child, then why isn't a pedometer a device for measuring children?

Comment: Because nobody felt the need for a word for "a device for measuring children"? This seems like asking why "informative" is not used to mean the opposite of "formative."

Comment: You left out pediatrician.

Comment: Yep that one too... Why isn't it podiatrician instead of podiatrist?  Language is so funny.

Comment: Because a podophile is someone with a foot fetish.

Comment: There already is a word for a device for measuring children.  It's called a tape measure.

Comment: I thought that device was called a wall...

Comment: I think its a little simplistic to define a pedophile as "someone with a sexual interest in children." The word "interest" is the culprit; what do you really mean by "interest"? Suppose, for example, we're talking about a good & empathic & self-regulating pedophile; so, this person is *attracted* to children, but they have absolutely no *interest* in having sex with children and they do their best to manage their unethical appetites and live a moral life. If our definition of a pedophile is "someone with a sexual interest in children," then arguably this kind of person is not...

Comment: ...a pedophile. Well, you can set-up your definitions this way if you please, but I prefer to refer to consider *anyone* with a sexual appetite for children as a pedophile, and to distinguish between *regulated* versus *non-regulated* pedophilia. On the latter is truly problematic. More generally, I think the way we use English to talk about what people want is often fraught with problematically-high levels of ambiguity.

Answer (score 10):

You got two different [Ablaut grades](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/94837/15299) of the same root, plus a different root here.

One root is Proto-Indo-European [**ped-*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/_/roots.aspx?type=Indo-European&root=ped-) 'foot', as noted. This comes in two varieties:

- the **E-grade**, represented in Latin *pedis* 'foot', with root *ped-*
- the **O-grade**, represented in Greek *podos* 'foot', with root *pod-*

English borrowed lots of words with both of these roots:
*podiatrist* (< Gk *iatros*, 'physician'), *podium, pedal, pedometer* (< Lat *meter* 'measure').

The other root is PIE [**pau-*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/_/roots.aspx?type=Indo-European&root=pau-) 'small; child', the source of Latin *parvus* 'small',
and Greek *paidos* 'child'. Words from Greek and Latin with *AI*  or *AE* in them
tended to be borrowed into English with an *E*, so we get words from *paidos* like
*pediatrician* (< Gk *iatros*), *pedagogue* (< Gk *agogos*, 'leader'), *pedophile* (< Gk *philos*, 'love')

---

**Postnote**: The Latin root *pod* is the same as the pre-Germanic root, but all the Germanic languages went through a series of regular sound changes called "Grimm's Law", in which
PIE **p* changed to *f*, and PIE **d* changed to *t*, leaving the Proto-Germanic root **fot-*,
which is the source of English *foot*.

Same thing for *pater* and *father*, (**t* changed to *th*) *canis* and *hound* (**k* changed to *h*),
*cardium* and *heart*,  etc. If you understand Grimm's Law, you double your English vocabulary.

Comment: While *pedagogue* is commonly found in British English, the other words are *paediatrician* and *paedophile*. It's only adherents of Webster's AmE spelling which generally reduced the digraphs who may be misled. BrE shows the different roots between *pedometer* and *paedometer*.

Comment: Bully for British spelling, then! But then people will wonder how to spell _pædiatrician_.

Answer (score 3):

Overwhelmingly, it is considered that paedophilia (although I  can't attest to the spelling 100% as I do not have an original copy of the work) was first used in print in Richard von Krafft-Ebing's 'Psychopathia Sexualis'. One assumes that as much of this tome was written in Latin and Greek he would be quite knowledgeable in these languages. So I imagine that the reason he did NOT use 'paedophilia' (or 'pedophilia') to describe a sexual attraction to prepubescent children is because he knew that that's not what it meant. What he did do was to use the word in conjunction with the qualifying term 'erotica' to describe this condition as he saw it.

In fact there are many Greek words for love, although it's usually the four main ones that are commonly cited;
Storge – empathy bond.
Philia – friend bond.
Eros – romantic love.
Agape – unconditional "God" love.

This is probably largely as a result of C. S. Lewis's fascination in his 'The Four Loves'.

It's interesting to note that the -phile suffix is commonly used in a more objectively understood way than "friend bond". Such as in 'Francophile', 'Bibliophile', 'Oenophile' etc.
So as that I would expect 'Paedophile' to mean an objective but respectful interest in the subject of children. The same could be said for other words that have evolved a sexual connotation such as 'Necrophile' (eg: a Taxidermist) and 'Zoophile' (eg: David Attenborough).

One last point; many of these sexualised terms are grouped together under the heading 'Paraphilias'. Far from contradicting the above argument; para-, used here, infers "abnormal". Therefore, it is describing something that is not a true, normal, -philia, so thus it is effectively not a -philia.

Comment: Fascinating, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can answer this question by looking at the various etymologies of the words. A useful resource for looking up etymologies is [Etymonline.com](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php), which gives the following:

> ***[pedometer (n.)](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=pedometer)***
>
> instrument for measuring distances covered by a walker, 1723, from French *pédomètre* (1712), a hybrid coined from Latin *pedis* (genitive of *pes* "foot;" see **foot** (n.)) + Greek *metron* "a measure" (see **meter** (n.2)). At first Englished as *waywiser*.

and

> [***pedophile (n.)***](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=pedophile&allowed_in_frame=0)
>
> 1951, derived noun from **pedophilia**.

and

> ***[pedophilia (n.)](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=pedophilia&allowed_in_frame=0)***
>
> 1900, from Greek *pais* (genitive *paidos*) "child" (see **pedo-**) + *philos* "loving" see **-phile**). First attested in an abstract of a report by Krafft-Ebing.

As you can see, *pedometer* comes from Latin via French. The Latin root is *pedis* (notice the 'd'), meaning "of feet".

*Pedophile* comes from Greek. The root is *paidos* (notice the 'd'), meaning "of children."

Don't make the mistake of thinking every time you see ***pedo-*** in a word, it means "of children". Sometimes it means "of children" (following the Greek etymology) and sometimes it means "of feet" (following the Latin etymology).

The same goes for ***pod-***. You have to look at the specific etymologies to see where the prefix is coming from originally.

Comment: Interesting... so basically there is no real rhyme or reason, just some words came into the popular usage via one country of origin, and others via another.  If you didn't already know what the intended meaning was, you'd have to look it up.

Comment: @JonathanvanClute It's nothing so neat as country of origin. English is the result of mixing the languages of Celts, Danes, Norse, Angles, Saxons, Romans, Normans, et al. Greek influenced Latin, which came via the Romans during their conquest of Britain and via the Normans (since the Romans conquered Gaul before the Normans conquered England) and via its use as a European scientific  lingua franca. Then the English conquered the rest of the world and pillaged the languages they found thereby.

Comment: @deadrat Sounds about right +1 (but you may have missed one)

Answer (score 2):

The etymology of the word "pedophile" as I know it is fraught with peril. As I recall it, the word should be spelled and pronounced as [pædophile](http://www.tfd.com/p%C3%A6dophile).

In print, you can see the word [paedophile](http://www.tfd.com/p%C3%A6dophile) in the Collins English Dictionary – Complete and Unabridged, 12th Edition. The paedophile spelling goes back as far as 1908, whereas the pedophile spelling only started appearing in 1944 according to the [Google Ngrams library](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=paedophile%2C+pedophile&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpaedophile%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpedophile%3B%2Cc0). It looks like the word was just too difficult to properly enunciate for most people, so the spelling was changed to reflect the common pronunciation when it started becoming popularized amongst the general public.

However those ae/æ words have been seemingly evicted from the language. Yeah, the [Encyclopædia Britanica](https://www.britannica.com) still uses the Encyclopædia spelling and have been [since at least the 9th edition](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/culture/books/9143431/The-dull-but-dependable-Encyclopaedia-Britannica-bows-to-the-digital-facts-of-life.html) which is significant but as far as I know everybody else, including the now much more known [Wikipedia, the free Encyclopedia](https://www.wikipedia.org/) uses the alternate spelling. The Google nGrams are pretty condemning here too as the [Encyclopædia](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=encyclop%C3%A6dia&year_start=1739&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cencyclop%C3%A6dia%3B%2Cc0) spelling has been declining in isolation from the other variants and [isn't even a blip on the radar by means of comparison](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=encyclop%C3%A6dia%2C+encyclopedia%2C+encyclopaedia&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cencyclop%C3%A6dia%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cencyclopedia%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cencyclopaedia%3B%2Cc0) if you discount what's arguably the most significant historical use of the word.

Do note that this makes so much more sense with [The Online Etymology Dictionary etymology entry](http://etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=pedophile) Silenus already mentioned:

> 1900, from Greek pais (genitive **paidos**) "child" (see pedo-) + philos "loving" see -phile). First attested in an abstract of a report by Krafft-Ebing.

The emphasis is my own, to emphasize the probable pronunciation of the word-forming element we probably *should* be using, if people weren't lazy and the cause wasn't hopeless. Oh well, at least it's not like pedophile ever meant anything else in English as far as I know, although it does seem to deny foot fetishists the unique single word they should rightfully own (which is not to say that anybody would want the name at this point anyway). Regardless, if not only in order to further emphasize this point, let's go look at the referenced entry at The Online Etymology Dictionary too:

> [Pedo](http://etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=pedo-) before vowels ped-, word-forming element meaning "boy, child," from Greek pedo-, comb. form of pais "boy, child," especially a son, from PIE root *peu- "small, little, few, young" (see few (adj.)). The British form paed- is better because it avoids confusion with ped-.
>
> ---
>
> paedo- see pedo-.

[A recent use of the word can be found in Stop Using the Word Paedophile, written
by Julie Bindel for The Guardian.](https://web.archive.org/web/20150429122122/http://www.theguardian.com/commentisfree/2006/may/23/letsstopusingthewordpaedo)

---

**Citations and Alternate links:**

Wiktionary entries for [pædophile](https://www.wordnik.com/words/p%C3%A6dophile) and [encyclopædia](https://www.wordnik.com/words/encyclop%C3%A6dia), reproduced on Wordnik.

[The Collins English Dictionary – Complete and Unabridged, 12th Edition's entry for paedophile.](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/paedophile?s=t)

[As stated by Stop Using the Word Paedophile, written
by Julie Bindel for The Guardian and published Tuesday 23 May 2006: Archived on The Internet Archive's Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20150429122122/http://www.theguardian.com/commentisfree/2006/may/23/letsstopusingthewordpaedo)

[This is the present Encyclopædia Britanica's homepage, archived on The Internet Archive's Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20160101000856/http://www.britannica.com)

There is a photograph on [The Dull but Dependable Encyclopaedia Britannica Bows to the Digital Facts of Life by Max Davidson for The Telegraph 14 Mar 2012, archived on The Internet Archive's Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/save/http://www.telegraph.co.uk/culture/books/9143431/The-dull-but-dependable-Encyclopaedia-Britannica-bows-to-the-digital-facts-of-life.html)

[This is Wikipedia Homepage, 31 Mar 01 snapshot, archived on The Internet Archive's Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20010331173908/http://www.wikipedia.com/)

[This is a Screenshot of the Google Ngrams Usage Trends Comparison for, Encyclopaedia, Encyclopædia and encyclopedia.](https://postimg.org/image/pb84cz5a1/)

[This is Screenshot of the Google Ngrams Usage Trends Comparison for Paedophile, Pedophile](https://postimg.org/image/bgfvzl7fz/)

[This is a Google nGrams Screenshot for the usage trend of Encyclopædia, which is isolated from other words](https://postimg.org/image/fpx8iaulb/)

[This is The Online Etymology Dictionary's Entry for pedophile: Archived on The Internet Archive's Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20160404195050/http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=pedophile&allowed_in_frame=0)

[This is The Online Etymology Search Results Page for pedo-, with the paedo wordforming element](https://web.archive.org/web/20160819035510/http://etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=pedo-)

[Here are scholarly citations](http://etymonline.com/sources.php?allowed_in_frame=0) for The Online Etymology Dictionary, [and an archival link to them The Internet Archive's wayback machine.](https://web.archive.org/web/20160412050427/http://etymonline.com/sources.php?allowed_in_frame=0)

Comment: "ae" - > "e" is much more the case in American English. In Britain the "a"  is retained in "paed-", thus avoiding the ambiguity between feet and children.

Comment: "the -phile suffix doesn't even mean an erotic sort of love in Greek" This is debatable. There's a tradition in philosophy/theology of drawing fine distinctions between various [Greek words for love](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greek_words_for_love). However, that Wikipedia article notes that Aristotle used "philia" to refer to love between lovers, [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/φιλία#Greek) lists "sexual love" as one meaning...

Comment: and [*The Online Liddell-Scott-Jones Greek-English Lexicon*](http://stephanus.tlg.uci.edu/lsj/#eid=114018&context=lsj&action=from-search) includes the definition "later, of lovers, *fondness*."

Comment: There are several other problems with this answer I need to address later. I think the Online Etymology Dictionary entry addresses Chris's concern sufficiently until then, since it notes that paedophile is the British form. @sumelic Secondhand information is problematic like that. I'll remove that portion of the answer for now since it's nonessential, re-purpose the reference (which didn't address what I originally thought it did anyway) and let you know when I have references I can fully parse. It'd be nice if you can give me a more precise date than "later" in the meantime. Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know Greek, so all of my information is also second-hand. I was just quoting LSJ, which is considered a good dictionary of ancient Greek. Using Google Books, I found a passage from [*The Greeks and Greek Love: A Bold New Exploration of the Ancient World](https://books.google.com/books?id=PijaG8n5Zz8C&pg=PA30&lpg=PA30&dq=greek+philia+really+friendly&source=bl&ots=9jtyvOloeq&sig=aCMFhlLGyt3hovKkbP-ioK8tils&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiGvJS3ns3OAhWBXiYKHe-tAbMQ6AEIUzAI#v=onepage&q=greek%20philia%20really%20friendly&f=false),*
by James N. Davidson...

Comment: that seems relevant and gives a more detailed explanation of the word's connotations, with some examples from ancient authors, but the book's title suggests that this author may be presenting a new interpretation that is not the consensus in the field (or at least, that was not the consensus at the time it was published: 2007).

Answer (score 1):

Also I think you're confusing the way o Meter works as a suffix. Kind of like a speedometer or a tachometer, it is Ped-ometer.  Not pedo-meter.

Comment: So it's ped (foot) then O then Meter.  So foot of measure.. or measuring of feet

Comment: This isn't the entire story, however. There are plenty of words that have only a -meter suffix: altimeter,  velocimeter,  gravimeter, etc.

Comment: @Laurel -o/-i meter. Just a glue vowel

Comment: @Carly Ammeter,  voltameter,  acoumeter... I have more examples, although not all of them are well-known.