# Why are there different vowels in the words "podiatry, podium" and "pedicure, pedestrian"?

Tags: etymology, orthography

There are some words like "podiatry, podium" and "pedicure, pedestrian" which are etymologically cognate and very close in their semantics.
At least, the first morpheme in all of them is the same.
Why, then, is there a vowel change?

Comment: You're asking about the "o" vs. the "e" in the first syllable? There was a previous question about "pod" and "ped": [Podiatrist vs. pedometer vs. pedophile?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/343584)

Answer (score 1):

The answer lies in the origins of the words. The first two are of Greek origin, the latter two are derived from Latin. *Etymonline* explains (with minor edits from me)

Greek origin

> [**podiatry**](https://www.etymonline.com/word/podiatry): 1914, formed from **Greek** ***pod-***, stem of ***pous*** "foot" (from PIE root *ped- "foot")
>   [**podium**](https://www.etymonline.com/word/podium): 1743, … from Latin *podium* "raised platform," from **Greek** ***podion*** "foot of a vase," diminutive of ***pous*** (genitive *podos*) "foot,…

Latin origin

> [**pedicure**](https://www.etymonline.com/word/pedicure): 1839, "one whose business is surgical care of feet"
>    (removal of corns, bunions, etc.), from French *pédicure*, **from Latin *pes*** (genitive *pedis*) "foot" (from PIE root *ped- "foot") + curare "to care for," from cura "care".
>   **[pedestrian](https://www.etymonline.com/word/pedestrian)** 1716, "prosaic, dull" (of writing), from **Latin** ***pedester*** (genitive *pedestris*) "plain, not versified, prosaic," literally "on foot" (sense contrasted with *equester* "on horseback"), from ***pedes*** "one who goes on foot," from ***pes*** (genitive pedis) "foot,"

Comment: I could expand this answer (why was Greek preferred instead of Latin and vice versa) but I lack the time to do the proper research.