# How to use the word alive as an adjective in a sentence?

Tags: adjectives, adverbs, adjective-position, predicate-adjectives, postpositive

Example:

> She returned from spiritual retreat "vividly" (OR FULL OF LIFE)

Is *alive* a postpositive adjective?

---

If I want to say: She returned from spiritual retreat "ALIVELY" (refering to FULL OF LIFE). Is "ALIVELY" (incorrect) an adverb? since I can't find a way to turn the adjective ALIVE into an adverb, and I can't find the adverb "ALIVELY" as such.

Comment: Your example doesn't include the word "alive."

Comment: You will need to go to some trouble to make "alive" mean "full of life" instead of "not dead". It would be clearer to just use the phrase "full of life".

Comment: Just *more alive* or *energized* would get your point across without made-up words.

Comment: [Alive](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/alive) can mean "marked by alertness" or "marked by much life, activity", but generally this is only in fixed expressions ("came alive", "alive with X"), and I absolutely agree that "not dead" is the normal meaning in most contexts with people ("functional", "switched on" for machines).

Comment: _Alively_ would be an adverb if it existed, but it doesn't. You don't need an adverb here; you are not describing the manner in which she returned, but the state she was in at the time. _Alive_ on its own won't do, since it would just indicate that she wasn't dead, but you could say _vividly alive_.

Answer (score 2):

Postpositive adjectives are part of noun phrases: the president *elect*, any students *absent*, etc.

Adjectives can generally be used either as attributive modifiers (*alive* doesn't allow this except when it has a modifier like *half*), postpositives, or predicatively (both of the latter are allowed by *alive*):

> *The *alive* organism moved around. [not allowed]
>
> Even a *half alive* virus contributes to the biosphere. [attributive]
>
> The only thing *alive* in this room is that machine. [postpositive]
>
> He looks *alive* and healthy, tanned as a shiny penny, trim as a trout. [predicative]

Comment: I had initially thought he just meant that *she returned alive*, but apparently not. :)

Answer (score 0):

You probably mean that she returned ***revived***:

> revive 
> give new life or energy to ([Vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/revive))

or ***invigorated***

> made or become fresh in spirits or vigor ([M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/invigorated))

Answer (score 0):

The idiomatic expression is "feeling alive":

> She returned from the retreat feeling alive.

It would be understood to mean fev's **(re)invigorated** or **revived**.

Answer (score 0):

A subject-orientated secondary predicate [according to some grammarians] (arguably depictive, arguably resultative) is probably what you're seeking. But

- *She returned from her spiritual retreat alive*

doesn't work for two reasons, the first being that the default sense of 'alive' is 'not dead' here, as remarked by Peter.

But the fact that

- *He appeared at last out of the jungle[,] alive*

sounds far less natural than

- *He appeared at last out of the jungle, alive and kicking*

shows that not all such constructions work equally well.

- *She returned from her spiritual retreat vivacious*

doesn't sound at all natural, whereas

- *She returned from her spiritual retreat refreshed and revitalised*

sounds fine.

- *She returned from her spiritual retreat full of vim and vigour*

is equally idiomatic, slightly less formal.